# Finding a constant $M$ through quadratic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $a,b,c$ be integers and let$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$$has an irrational root $r$. Let $u=\frac{p}{q}$ be any rational number such that $\vert {u-r}\vert <1$. Prove that

$$\Biggl(\frac {1}{q^2} \le \vert f(u)\vert\le K\vert{u-r}\vert\Biggr)$$for some constant $K$.Deduce that there is a constant $M$ such that
$$\left| r\frac{p}{q}\right| \ge \frac{M}{q^2}$$

Stuck in this question for many days. Can someone help ?

Comment: $a r^2+b r+c=0$ then $c=-ar^2-br\quad.$ Furthermore $f(u)=a u^2+b u+c=au^2+bu-ar^2-br=(u-r) (a r+a u+b)\quad.$ then $|f(u)|=|u-r|\cdot | a r+a u+b|=K|u-r|\le K\quad.$ where $K=a r+a u+b$

Comment: @Raffaele $M$ ??

Comment: This is all I did

Comment: @sayan: Are you sure the last inequality shouldn't be $\;\biggl| r\color{red}-\dfrac pq\biggr|\ge\dfrac{M}{q^2}$?

Comment: @Bernard I am quite  sure that I am correct but It would help if you posted a solution taking it as you have said

Answer (score 0):

If $r$ is an irrational root, then the other root $r′$ must also be irrational

Now $|f(u)|=\frac{|ap^2+bpq+cq^2|}{q^2}$
. This numerator is an integer, so it is either $0$, or $≥1$. If it is $0$, then divide by $q^2$ and get $f(\frac{p}{q})=0$. But this means that $f$ has a rational root, impossible according to the first paragraph. So, $\frac{1}{q^2}≤|f(u)|$

.

Also, since $f(r)=0$
, $$|f(u)|=|f(u)−f(r)|=|a(u^2−r^2)+b(u−r)|=|u−r|⋅|a(u+r)+b|$$ $$|u+r|=|−r−u|=|−2r+r−u|≤2|r|+|r−u|≤2|r|+1$$ $$|a(u+r)+b|≤|a|⋅|u+r|+|b|≤|a|(2|r|+1)+|b|$$. If you call this last number K, then $|f(u)|≤K|u−r|$

Finally, take the endpoints of this inequality, $\frac{1}{q^2}≤K|u−r|$
, multiply them by $|u|$ and get $$\frac{|u|}{q^2} ≤K|u^2−ur|≤Ku^2+K|ur|$$. Therefore $$|\frac{p}{q}r|≥\frac{|u|}{Kq^2}−u^2$$ and, if you let $M=\frac{|u|}{K}−u^2q^2$, this can be rewritten as $$|\frac{p}{q}r|≥\frac{M}{q^2}$$.